# How Do I clean the "Look in" history in "Find and Replace" window in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

How Do I clean the "Look in" list history in "Find and Replace" window in Visual Studio 2013?

[image]

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/403245/how-can-i-remove-items-from-the-look-in-combo-box-in-visual-studios-find-an

Comment: @Cody Gray - thanks!

Comment: Note that questions cannot be closed as duplicates of questions on another site, so that if solution works for you, you should post an answer of your own and accept it (when the system eventually lets you). A link giving credit back to the original source would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to delete the entries located in the following registry key:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Find
```

They will be prefixed with Query and then followed by a number.

Thanks for **Cody Gray** that provide me the link to the solution:
https://superuser.com/questions/403245/how-can-i-remove-items-from-the-look-in-combo-box-in-visual-studios-find-an