# Clear custom Look In entries from the Search and Replace dialog

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

How can I remove entries I previously created from the *Look in* drop down menu of the *Find and Replace* dialog in Visual Studio 2017?

[image]

I have found several topics on this (for example, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35684726/how-do-i-clean-the-look-in-history-in-find-and-replace-window-in-visual-stud)), but none seem to work. Their solution always rely on some `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Find` register key (version may vary), but I cannot find it for Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem that for Visual Studio 2017, these keys have been moved to an external "hive", which is located under:

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_6b904c09
```

(Your Visual Studio version may vary). Look for this file: `privateregistry.bin`

[image]

Basically, we now need to load this into RegEdit before we can access the registry key we are interested in. Here are the complete steps:

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Open RegEdit.
3. Navigate to `HKEY_USERS`.
4. Click on : File -> Load Hive... (This will not work if not on `HKEY_USERS`).
5. Select file `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_6b904c09\privateregistry.bin`. Your version of Visual Studio may vary.
6. Select a key name. The hive should then be loaded under that name. I chose "temp" for this example, since this is temporary.
7. In RegEdit, navigate to `HKEY_USERS/temp/Software/Microsoft/VisualStudio/15.0_6b904c09/Find/Named`.
8. Under there, you will find your list of "Find In Files" folder-sets. Delete the ones you don't want.
9. When done, move the current selection back to your temporary hive root (loaded in 4).
10. Unload it : File -> Unload Hive...

---

Source : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unable-to-delete-from-look-in-list-in-find-in-file/254801

Comment: In VS16 the named locations are in the /Find path, with `ScopeN` keys, where N is 0,1,2...